# Tenor Banjo Tuning

Tags: tuning, banjo

Have aquired a tenor banjo and do not know how I should tune it up. The nut to bridge is 23 inches in length so is completely different from my current soprano ukulele. I seek advice as to how to tune the tenor banjo.

Answer (score 4):

Although your title says tenor Ukulele, I'm assuming it is a Tenor Banjo since the scale length is 23 inches. The longest scale length for a Ukulele is The Baritone Ukulele that comes in at 19 - 21.5 inches.

You can tune a Tenor Banjo a number of different ways, depending on what string gauges you use. There are string packs available for most tuning setups.

Common tuning includes:

- Bottom four strings of a guitar: D G B E.
- "standard" Tenor: C G D A
- "Irish" Tenor: G D A E

I've met some players that tune like a 5 string banjo without the high G string: D G B D or C G C D.

Which tuning you choose may be influenced by what style of music you want to play on it. Tenor guitar tuning is useful if you already play guitar or ukulele. "Irish" tuning useful if you want to play traditional Irish tunes &c.

EDIT:
If you are interested in playing it as if it were a Ukulele, then I would suggest Baritone Ukulele tuning, which is often tuned like the bottom 4 strings of a guitar D G B E.